# Solr child document with data import handler

Tags: mysql, search, solr, lucene

I use Solr's DIH to import data from MySQL database. My data-config is defined as:

```
<document>
    <entity name="PARENT" query="SELECT * FROM PARENT">
        <field name="id" column="id" />
        <entity name="CHILD" child="true" query="SELECT * FROM CHILD WHERE id = ${PARENT.id}">
            <field name="id" column="id" />
            <field name="field1" column="field2" />
            <field name="field1" column="field2" />
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

I had to include an id field in the child document and a *root* field in the schema.xml. However the imported document was not like

```
{
    id:1
    {
        field1:
        field2:
        field3:
    }
},
{
    id:2
    {
        field1:
        field2:
        field3:
    }
}
```

, but like

```
{
    id:1
    field1:
    root:1
},
{
    id:1
    field2:
    root:1
},
{
    id:1
    field3:
    root:1
},
```

Is this intended result? Could anyone show me what is the correct config for importing nested entity from MySQL using DIH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points to mention:

1. As per documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler),

   Note that 'entity' elements can be nested, and this allows the entity
    relationships in the sample database to be mirrored here, so that we can
    generate a denormalized Solr record which may include multiple features
    for one item

   So even though the structure of entity, in xml is like parent-child, it says that solr stores internally as denormalized. So that is hat happening here
2. Are you getting id of child separatel? I can see that, the root is repeated in all child docs, which is expected, but id(assuming that it s child id) is also same, which is wierd. Can you confirm that.

When adding docs in solr, using nested concept, you alsways get 1+n documents, where 1 is parent, n is children

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unsure of the use of id field in child entity. Children are supposed to be part of their parent, when you locate the parent entity you should also be able to locate the child. _root_ makes sense here but why was id also present? In Json database you never need to supply id for child entities. And yes, there were n+1 documents per entity but the parent entity appeared to be having the same level of depth with children. Although block join can query the parent document it would be much simpler and more efficient to have children stored "inside" the parent.

Comment: As long as you have a separate id for child, it should be ok. Having separate id for chldren, is your requirement. Solr has a feature for default id's i suppose. Solr works best, when data is denormalized. I think, nested entities is just an abstraction to allow outside world to view the documents in terms of relation, but internally, as you see they are denormalized. And as you said, as long as you have block joins, you can get children from parents and vice versa. So I hope ALL IS FINE here

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. Also I saw a lot ppl mentioned a patch to DIH (SOLR-5147) which can enable block index. Is this patch already included in the newest version or I need to apply it manually?

Comment: I just found this article http://heliosearch.org/expand-block-join/ which was exactly what you said. Denormalized structure is intended in solr.

Comment: Hi, SOLR-5147, seemed to be fixed in version 5.1. The fact that you can see all documents added, means that your DIH is supporting the feature to index child documents. Please verify using block joins, to confirm that the searching part is also working fine. And for your update comment, Yes - solr works best with denormalized. But sometimes its tough to index all data in that format, so may be its better the framework decides waht to do, and we can add from an abstraction layer - which is like above, and in solrj **solrInputDocument.addChildren()** etc.. Happy learning